# How to send commit message as email body post Jenkins downstream job completed successfully

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I have a 5 freestyle Jenkins job which are dependent on each other, if 1st one is successful, 2nd will get trigger and so on.

For 1st Job, I have enabled webhook from Bitbucket & on every push to testbranch (branch name), Jenkins pipeline will get triggered.

I wanted to send, commit message of every push to bitbucket testbranch as an email body to email-recipient post successful execution of 5th job.

Eg: `git commit -m "TEST COMMIT 5"`, I want to send this commit message to email recipients as it is.

When I used the in-built Jenkins Env variable for Git in my jenkins job build body, I am seeing commit message is coming as encoded not an exact message:

Execute shell body:

```
echo "Commit message: $GIT_COMMIT \n Git Branch: $GIT_BRANCH
```

I am expecting o/p as:

```
Commit message: "TEST COMMIT 5" \n Git Branch: origin/testbranch
```

But I am getting o/p as :

```
 Commit message: 63c4lkahdu772jd791ok918523151701742c \n Git Branch: origin/testbranch
```

I wanted to declare the commit message variable as global and will pass it as post build env variable but before doing that, need to get the exact commit message to be aligned with it but not a encoded commit string.

Answer (score 1):

The `GIT_COMMIT` variable is to print Git Commit HASH value. There is no default variable to get Git commit message ([Doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#environment-variables)). But you if you are on a location where your git repo is cloned, you can use following command to filter Git message.

```
GIT_MESSAGE =$(git log -1 --pretty=%B ${GIT_COMMIT})
```

Later you can use `GIT_MESSAGE` variable anywhere.

Comment: Hi Saurabh,Thanks for the update. I have tried and getting the plain text value of git message. Wherein, when I tried to pass the GIT_MESSAGE as Predefined variable or inject as an env variable, it didnt work and not passing the variable to next job.